# serve a feed using Google Apps Script

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, deployment, feed

I used the Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) to create a feed. The only difference is that I have declared the file `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>` in place of `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

However, after having deployed my script as a web app, I realized that Google put the HTML content inside a sandbox frame, and so the feed declaration is not recognized.
So, I want to know if there is some workaround or other way to deploy a xml feed on the web using Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get this done using [Content Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content)

I have not used this thing exactly for XML before but I have done some project in which I had to design some simple API which outputs the JSON data, so there I have used this.

I think you can simply put your xml file in a separate file (for code readability and maintainability) and then from your main script file (usually `code.js`) you can fetch the content of that file and then convert the output into simple  text (maybe you can try using `getContent()` or `getContentAsString()`) depending upon the situation. And then at last just output that using `ContentService`

```js
function doGet() {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Hello, world!');
}
```

This is my opinion, kindly let me know if this works or if you need any more suggestions.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content